# Compare the growth of given functions.

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

Compare the growth of the following 2 functions:

$$n^{\log \log \log n}$$
$$(\log n)!$$

**My solution**:

Let $n=2^m$

$$n^{\log \log \log n}=(2^m)^{\log \log \log_2 m}$$
$$=(2^m)^{\log \log m)}$$
$$=(\log m)^{\log 2^m}$$
$$=(\log m)^m$$

$$(log n)! = (log_2 2^m)!$$
$$= m!$$

Now I don't understand as to  how to compare between

$$(\log m)^m$$
AND
$$ m!$$

It would be a great if someone could help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: What does $(\log n)!$ even mean?

Comment: You may use [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) with $\log n$ as the input inside of the Factorial.

Comment: Have you tried Stirling as suggested yesterday?  It will solve your problem.  Again, let $m=2^k$ so the log comes out even.

Comment: Thanks @RossMillikan. Stirling's approximation did solve my problem.